# return in short-hand if

Tags: c#

I try to rewrite this method using short-hand if:

```
 public string checkInputParamters(string baseUrl, string owner, string documentId, string user, string secret, string type)
    {
      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(baseUrl)) 
          return ExceptionsCodes.BASE_URL_CANNOT_BE_NULL_OR_EMPTY.ToString("g");

      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(owner))
          return ExceptionsCodes.OWNER_CANNOT_BE_NULL_OR_EMPTY.ToString("g");

      return "";
    }
```

I cannot do like this because return forces me to put a value after ":" iso ";".

```
 public string checkInputParamters(string baseUrl, string owner, string documentId, string user, string secret, string type)
    {
       return ((null == baseUrl) || (string.Empty == baseUrl)) ? ExceptionsCodes.BASE_URL_CANNOT_BE_NULL_OR_EMPTY.ToString("g");
       return ((null == owner) || (string.Empty == owner)) ? ExceptionsCodes.OWNER_CANNOT_BE_NULL_OR_EMPTY.ToString("g");
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: In the first example you aren't returning anything if both `if` statements are false. This will give a compile error. Could you correct your code?

Comment: what is the point of using a short-hand if ? it makes the code ugly and unreadable, especially in this case, whereas the two ´if´ in the above code are clear on the first sight.

Comment: Just a brief slightly offtopic comment: Cristian, did you know you can do `string.InNullOrEmpty( baseUrl )` to get those two checks into one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
return String.IsNullOrEmpty(baseUrl)
          ? YourBaseUrlException
          : String.IsNullOrEmpty(owner)
               ? YourOwnerException
               : "";
```

Answer (score 8):

Another thing to note is that you can replace

```
((null == owner) || (string.Empty == owner))
```

with

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(owner)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a default return if it isn't either one of these two cases.

For instance:

```
return String.IsNullOrEmpty(owner)?ExceptionsCodes.OWNER_BLAH.ToString("g"):(String.IsNullOrEmpty(baseUrl)?ExceptionsCodes.BASEURL_BLAH.ToString("g"):"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you had in mind?

```
public string checkInputParamters(string baseUrl, string owner, string documentId, string user, string secret, string type)
    {
        return String.IsNullOrEmpty(baseUrl) ? 
            ExceptionsCodes.BASE_URL_CANNOT_BE_NULL_OR_EMPTY.ToString("g") :
            ( String.IsNullOrEmpty(owner) ? ExceptionsCodes.OWNER_CANNOT_BE_NULL_OR_EMPTY.ToString("g") : "" );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The method has to return something. I doubt the top example compiles. (I see you changed it now.)

Combine the other two answers.

```
public string checkInputParamters(string baseUrl, string owner, string documentId, string user, string secret, string type)
{
  return String.IsNullOrEmpty(baseUrl) ?
      ExceptionsCodes.BASE_URL_CANNOT_BE_NULL_OR_EMPTY.ToString("g")
  : (String.IsNullOrEmpty(owner) ?
      ExceptionsCodes.OWNER_CANNOT_BE_NULL_OR_EMPTY.ToString("g")
  : String.Empty;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

imo, in this case a solution using the first examples layout is far more readable.  I would be more concerned about readability here rather than trying to [code-golf](http://codegolf.com/) your code.

Zombies solution of swapping in `String.IsNullOrEmpty(owner)` would be a nice enhancement.

Answer (score 0):

I personally dislike inline if but this should do the trick

```
            return (
                String.IsNullOrEmpty(baseUrl)?
                ExceptionsCodes.BASE_URL_CANNOT_BE_NULL_OR_EMPTY.ToString("g"):(
                    String.IsNullOrEmpty(owner)?
                    ExceptionsCodes.OWNER_CANNOT_BE_NULL_OR_EMPTY.ToString("g"):
                    string.Empty
                )
            );
```

Pretty much the same as everyone else is saying, I just like to have the (implied) ()'s clearly visible in inline ifs